# get child elements html

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code below in html and I need to modify in javascript the text "Second text" with something else.

```
<hr id="elemID"><b>First text</b> Second text
```

In javascript I have tried to get the children of "elemID", and modify their text:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elemID'); 
var child = elem.children[1];
child.innerHTML=\"Other text\";
```

I don't know if it is correct to consider that "Second text" is a child of "elemID".
How can I do something similar with what I need without using a `<p>` element. I need that "Second text" to be on the same line with "First text".

Comment: Can you surround all the text you need with a `span` element? This way you can give it an ID but it won't have any effect on screen

Comment: Why the aversion to adding a `<p>` element? It most likely won't help you to add a `<p>` node specifically, but I'm guessing you're against adding other markup too. So, **why**?

Comment: `<hr>` elements have no children. They're "void elements" which are elements whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances.

Comment: You could read the whole `<hr>` content and then split the string on the `</b>`

Comment: @Andi it's generally not good to use text manipulation instead of DOM manipulation, when DOM manipulation is possible. So, if you can do it with `.textContent`, like in my answer, it's best to use that instead.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Also `<hr>` doesn't have content :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, wrap the text node in a `<span>` element that you can identify:

```
<hr id="elemID"><b>First text</b><span id='second_text_span'> Second text</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the `<hr>` element is a self-closing element, it won't have any children. What the other elements are is siblings. So, to select the text node that contains `Second text`, you'll need to select the next sibling, and then the next after that:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elemID'); 
var textnode = elem.nextSibling.nextSibling;
textnode.textContent = "Other text";
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8svnm/)

Also, you shouldn't escape your quotes when you're creating a string. So, remove the backslashes from before the quotes around `Other text`.

Comment: This will work until you add a newline after the `<hr>` and then you need to skip three siblings ;-)

Comment: Yes, but I am assuming the HTML content is just as given by the asker.

Comment: I know you are; it's more for OP to note :) identifying text nodes reliably is tricky stuff.

Answer (score 1):

"Second text" is no child of HR. It's a childnode of it's parent above.
If you need to change your "second text" you should wrap it in a  tag and use this to change it's value.

```
<hr id="elemID"><b>First text</b> <span id="second">Second text</span>

document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = "Other text";
```

**edit**
all at the same time :-)
Joeytje50's seems the best to me.

Comment: This is the more reliable way :)